# create a com_record an object from a COM defined type

Tags: python, win32com

I am just starting to play around with win32com.client module to try and write a Python program that uses a COM interface to control MicroStation, much in the way I used to control MicroStation from Excel.

The problem I have is to create objects of a type defined in the COM library, a com_record, namely in my case a Point3d. The Point3d is basically a C structure of 3 double X,Y,Z.

```
struct Point3d {
    double X;
    double Y;
    double Z;
}
```

In Excel after referencing the MicrostationDGN library I had access to the Point3d datatype and could easily define new variables with `Dim newpoint As Point3d`

How can I do the same in Python?

Thanks,

PS. I have tried creating a C struct but that gives me an error

```
from ctypes import Structure, c_double

class Point3d(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('X', c_double),
                ('Y', c_double)]

startPoint = Point3d()
startPoint.X = 1
startPoint.Y = 1

TypeError: Only com_record objects can be used as records
```

Comment: I found some info here http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/How-to-create-a-com-record-td1953557.html but i still have no clue how to make the com_record object I require.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

Quoting (roughly) from the docs, you want:

```
Point3d = namedtuple('Point3d', ['x', 'y', 'z'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I just tried it but it generates the same error...
TypeError: Only com_record objects can be used as records

Comment: Sorry. I was trying to steer you away from ctypes and toward a pure python (named tuple) approach. But if you're planning to pass the resulting point objects to some routine not mentioned in your question, then yeah, you'll have to follow the docs for that interface. You mention an URL in your comment that suggests using windows-specific COM support, rather than python's portable ctypes support.

Answer (score 0):

I found this from the library author:

```
r = win32com.client.Record("RecordName", object)
```

> where "RecordName" is the name of the record, and 'object' is &any*
>   COM  object defined in the same type library.

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2003-August/214888.html

I could not find an object of that type to instantiate a com_record as described, but I managed to find a function that returns the object i need.

```
startPoint = MS.Point3dFromXYZ(2.0,2.0,0.0)
```